Intersecting a convex set with a ball exactly at two points
In the following I am using the usual Euclidean norm. Let $W\subset\mathcal{R}^2$ be a non-empty bounded convex set. Let $y_0\in \partial W$ (boundary of $W$). I want to argue: there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\forall 0<\delta'<\delta$, $B_{\delta'}(y_0)$ intersects with $\partial W$ exactly at two points. Is the statement true? If so, how can I make the argument rigorous? If not, could you please provide a counter example? By drawing diagrams in $\mathcal{R}^2$, my intuition tells me it should be true. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What do you mean by $B_{\delta'}(y_0)$? Is it the solid ball? If that is the case, your statement seems clearly wrong.

The intersection of two convex sets is convex. I find it hard for a convex set to contain exactly two points...

I am so sorry, I meant the intersection of their boundaries.

I will update the question.

And in case you want to intersect the boundary of a small ball with the boundary of the given set, the heuristic expectation would be that the intersection typically  "looks like" an $(n-2)$ sphere (and that only if we assume that $W$ has nonempty interior, i.e., doesn't fit into something lower dimensional)

Take the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The boundary of any ball centered on the boundary will intersect the boundary of the original sphere along a circle containing infinitely many points.

It might be true in two dimensions.

Let's reduce the problem into $\mathcal{R}^2$ since we can project. I will update the question again.

If your convex set is a segment, the boundary of a small ball centered at one of its end points intersects the segment (which is its own boundary)  just once. Your claim is thus not general.

It might be true for convex sets with non-empty interior.

@GReyes Thank you so much for pointing that out. I will update the question with this assumption.

Suppose $ W\subset\mathbb R^2$ is a convex set with nonempty interior and $p\in\partial  W$. Then for all sufficiently small positive$r$, $\partial B_r(p)$ intersects $\partial W$ in exactly two points.
To see this, let $a$ be an interior point of $W$ and start with a circle $\Gamma_1$ of radius $r_1< pa$. This circle will have at least two points $b$ and $c$ in common with $W$. Let $b'$ be the point on $\Gamma_1$ that is diametrically opposite ot $b$.
If $b'=c$, then $b,c\in\partial W$. Now any circle around $p$ that is small enough to not intersect the lines $ab$ and $ac$ will indersect $\partial W$ in exactly two points (both on the line $bc$).
The same argument works if $b'\in\partial W$.
So suppose $b'\ne c$ and $b'\notin \overline W$. Also suppose that $\angle cpb > 90^\circ$.
Consider any circle $\Gamma$ around $p$ of radius $r$ so small that $\Gamma$ does not intersect line $bc$, does not intersect the line through $c$ an dperpendicular to $bp$, and does not intersect the line through $b$ perpendicular to $pc$. Then the intersection of $\Gamma$ with line segment $pc$ belongs to $W$ and the intersection of $\Gamma$ with line segment $pb'$ is outside $W$ or at most on the boundary of $W$. Let $d$ be the point of $\overline W$ on the arc of $\Gamma$ between $pc$ and $pb'$ that minimizes $\angle b'pd$. Then $d\in\partial W$ and the interior of $\triangle pdc$ is in $W$. We find a second point ($e$, say) on the other side by interchanging the roles of $b$ and $c$. Then $d$ and $e$ are boundary points of $W$ and are the only such points on $\Gamma$ (why?).
Remains the case that we cannot achieve $\angle cpb>90^\circ.$ In that case, a similar construction works if we do not place $b'$ opposite to $b$ but rather at a $90^\circ$ angle.


Thank you so much for your answer. Let me digest this first.
